# Why does $| a_n + \frac {a_{n-1}} {z} + \ldots + \frac {a_{0}} {z^n} | \ge | a_n | - |\frac {a_{n-1}} {z} + \ldots + \frac {a_{0}} {z^n} |$ hold?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why does $$| a_n + \frac {a_{n-1}} {z} + \ldots + \frac {a_{0}} {z^n} | \ge | a_n | - |\frac {a_{n-1}} {z} + \ldots + \frac {a_{0}} {z^n} |$$ hold by the trinagle inequality for $z, a_i \in \mathbb C$ ?

Comment: This is just the reverse triangle inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $|x+y|\geq||x|-|y||\geq|x|-|y|$ , in this case $x=a_n$ and $y= \frac {a_{n-1}} {z} + \ldots + \frac {a_{0}} {z^n} $

Comment: Ahh, thank you.

Comment: @user111854 Glad I could help.

Comment: As in the other answer by user2345215, I find the inequality $|x+y| \ge |x| - |y|$ clearer when written as $|x-y| + |y| \ge |x|$.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a triangle inequality in disguise as it's equivalent to
$$\left|a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}z+\ldots+\frac{a_0}{z^n}\right|+\left|-\frac{a_{n-1}}z-\ldots-\frac{a_0}{z^n}\right|\ge|a_n|$$